# Efficient way of processing large data with Javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript

I use a third-party flash component (wrapped with Javascript) with my web application, from which I get comma-separated values and base64 data from it:

Get csv string as array function:

```
// Get the csv as array function
var buff = $wnd.MyFlashComp.getData();
var strBuff = buff.toString();
var arr = strBuff.split(',');
```

Get base64 data function:

```
// Get the data as base64 function
var buff64 = $wnd.MyFlashComp.getData64();
```

When I use buff64 and plug it in a HTML tag as base64 `src` data, the data is rendered properly in the browser, that is the page is still snappy. And I don't see any performance issue with the page.

However, the function that gets the csv as array is very slow, and makes the page hang if not lag. The data I'm getting from flash range from 500KB to 1MB in size (max).

Is there a way to improve performance of this code?

Comment: While you're at it, can you fix my engine on my car? ~~ We don't know what's taking so long so we can't tell you how to make it more efficient.

Comment: So from what I understand, the main problem is the `split`? or is it the download speed? Also, what data is in that CSV? Images? Are the images static? or are they different for each payload?

Comment: I presume the problem is with split, because the getData() is just getting the data from a flash component that did some data gathering on the client side. I am not doing any type of client-server at this point of the code

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer its an audio encoded as float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the main issue is the `split` because you are splitting 1MB of data, and you are on an HTML5 compliant (or modern) browser because of the base64, why not try doing the split in a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers).

---

Or if not on an HTML5 browser, do some manual async loop (a looping `setTimeout` with 1ms delay) and string manipulation. Do this by chopping off a comma-separated portion of the string for every iteration until none is left.

The `setTimeout` should aid you for a non-blocking operation, but I don't know how long it takes to chop off the entire 1MB this way. And this is not really "async". It just schedules the task per timeout so the operation won't block the UI. Additionally, per iteration, you could do a "progress report" for a progress bar but checking how much of the 1MB is remaining.

Comment: This solutions sounds efficient, I will try it. However, what if the user does not have HTML5 browser, what are the options of offloading the processing?

Comment: @xybrek then try doing an async loop using `setTimeout`.